# Replying to remote client via reply only?

Tags: akka, actor

According to the akka [actor documentation](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/scala/actors.html) one can reply using `self.channel ! Message` so the code will work locally. I would like to do the same with remote actors.

I have:

```
class ServerActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "Hello" =>
      self.channel ! "World"
  }
}
```

and

```
class ClientActor extends Actor { 
   val remote = ...

   def receive = {
      case "Start" =>
           remote ! "Hello" 
      case "World" => 
           println("World received")
   }
}
```

This works in so far as the `ServerActor` receives the "Hello" and sends a "World" message to a `ClientActor`. Unfortunately, it seems that the `ClientActor` receiving the message is one that is created in the servers VM, not the one that actually sent it (in the client VM).

Is there a way to make this work?

PS: It works when I do a `self reply "World"` and `remote ? "Hello"`, however, I would rather send a message than replying.

**EDIT:** Thanks to everyone. Starting remoting on both ends was the problem. Others finding this question beware: 
When using letting clients receive their responses in a non-blocking manner (as in not using `remote ? request`), shutting them down immediately on receiving a shutdown message, will cause some strange behavior (mentioned in my comments below); possibly by design due (to akka's let-it-fail fault-tolerance?). As clients are not waiting for a response shutting them down immediately on receiving a shutdown message will result in the following (on akka-1.2): Since the "original clients" no longer exist (but the round-trip "is still in progress") they are restarted --- strangely --- both on the client and the server.

Comment: It would definitely help me if you included what version you're using. Have you've started the remoting on both the client and the server?

Comment: @VictorKlang: Oh sure, this akka-1.2.
What do you mean by "remoting on both"? I only do `Actor.remote.start(...)` and `register` on the server. The client only calls `Actor.remote.actorFor(...)`.

Comment: You need to start the remoting on the client as well.

Comment: @ViktorKlang: thanks. 
Now I'm able to get the response(s) back most of the time. Somtimes (after a few 1000 calls from multiple clients) the serverVM starts throwing `ClassNotFoundException`s in `createClientManagedActor`... (it is that error is due to the fact that I'm using independent codebases [and classpaths] for client and server, so there's no way for the server to find the client class) ... which I guess means that the server is trying to (re?)start the client-actor on the client VM.

Comment: Great. I recommend turning off compression in the remoting since we've had quite some issues with it. Also, increasing the read-timeout of the client can be interesting from a performance perspective. Both these advice will be implemented by default in 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the [same problem I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674468/reply-is-not-transmitted-back-to-the-client-actor). You need to start up a server instance on the client aswell when you want receive messages from the server.

The exception is when you're explicitly are asking for a result with question-mark operator.